# Calling Dependency files from SVN repo

Tags: eclipse, selenium

As per my requirement i need to use jlibs and SauceRest dependencies from SVN repository in eclipse. Now i have jlibs and SauceRest commited in SVN repo.

Now could anyone guide how i can call those dependencies from my Pom.xml file and how i can import them to my project.

Could anyone share sample piece of code to achieve this????

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with check the whole project out. In your computer terminal, issue

`co http://yourprojecturl/yourpojectname localnameforyourpoject`.

Once this is completed, you can import the project in Eclipse. If you think this is too much, you can use an SVN plugin for Eclipse. [SubEclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is one and there are many more.